# Not found view in Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created `Area In ASP.NET MVC`. Like below.,

[image]

And in `CategoryController` I Write `Index Action` like This(CategoryController Inside AdminArea)

```
 public partial class CategoryController : Controller
 {
      public virtual ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View();
      }
 }
```

and `AdminAreaRegistration`

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

And create link like this.,

```
@Html.ActionLink("sss",MVC.Admin.Category.ActionNames.Index,MVC.Admin.Category.Name)
```

When i run website and while click on link i got this error.

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:

```
~/Views/Category/Index.aspx
~/Views/Category/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Category/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Category/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Comment: you simply have not created index.cshtml for the Category controller. Just right click on index action method and add view

Comment: If still confused see this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-view

Comment: @Ashwini Verma  : thanks but I have no problem with creating View

Comment: what is MVC.Admin.Category.ActionNames.Index in ActionLink.
Why can't you make it simple like.
@Html.ActionLink("sss", "Index", "Category", new {name = somename}, null)

Comment: @ Ashwini Verma : I Use T4MVC for Create Url and Action Index run but not found Index View.

Comment: @Pouya Why `virtual` Action Result method in your `controller`? Have defined your `routs` properly for the `Areas`?

Comment: @RJK :Thans for answer me.I Update Question and  Add AdminAreaRegistration Code

Comment: Hope you resolved the issue. If not refer the below answer. And +1 for you question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the way you called the `Controller and action` from your view `link`. And also why we need the `virtual keyword in ActionResult`. So, Do like below...

`Its working for me`.

**In your Admin Area Registration:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.Areas.Admin
{
    public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**In Your Category Controller:** Remove the <strike>`virtual`</strike> keyword.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestScoff.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class CatgoryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Your Link Should be Like below:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Here to Go Catgory", "Index", "Catgory")
```

**Note:** ***In Browser your Link will be come like this*** `http://localhost:54230/Admin/Catgory`

[Click here for simple reference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/areas-in-Asp-Net-mvc3/).